# how to know in nightwatch.js to that line has executed?

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, nightwatch.js

I am new on nightwatch.js, i am testing a web page, i want to know my code's particular line are executing or not, i tried myself and i written console.log(data); but when i am running my test.js file i can see console.log executed very first time without executing that line where this console.log was written in code.

so how can i detect that a particular line has been executed, i have gone through somewhere that we can't detect line execution in nightwatch.js because it sends asynchronous calls, so it is not possible. *i am still not sure that detecting lines execution is not possible.*

i have written code as following.

```
module.exports = {
     before : function (browser) {
     console.log('dummy string');
    },
     after : function (browser) {
     browser.end();
    },

   'Testing the seekbar' : function(browser) {
      browser.pause(4000);
      browser.click('.base.audio.tobevisible');
      myControl.moveToElement('@seekbar',80,50);
      myControl.click('@seekbar');
      console.log('dummy string1');
      browser.pause(1000);
      myControl.moveToElement('@seekbar',150,0);
      myControl.click('@seekbar');
      browser.pause(2000);
      console.log('dummy string2');
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Nighwatch.js commands have an optional callback argument to be passed as the last argument:

```
browser.click('@seekbar', function(response){
  console.log('dummy string1');
});
```

Check the doc of commands: http://nightwatchjs.org/api#commands

.click(selector, callback)
http://nightwatchjs.org/api/click.html

.moveToElement(selector, xoffset, xoffset, callback)
http://nightwatchjs.org/api/moveToElement.html

Comment: Thank you NicoPennec! :) Its working fine, can we pass any object also in this console.log ?

Comment: yes of course, for eg. an object : console.log('message', response) or console.log('a message', JSON.stringify( response, null, 2) )

Comment: Thank you once again! :)